# Children of View Parent from ScrollView not filling space?

Tags: css, react-native

this is the result:

[image]

This is my code:

```
  <ScrollView
    style={styles.container}
  >
    <View style={styles.section}>
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Sort By</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={[styles.group, { flex: 1, flexGrow: 1 }]}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={[
            { flex: 1, flexGrow: 1 },
          ]}
        >
          <Text>
            Distance
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={[
            { flex: 1, flexGrow: 1 }
          ]}
        >
          <Text>
            Ratings
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={[
            { flex: 1, flexGrow: 1 }
          ]}
        >
          <Text>
            Reviews
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  </ScrollView>
```

I have all the child having flex: 1, but why does it doesn't fill all the space? i tried width: 100% anywhere and nothing worked. below is my stylesheet:

```
export const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff"
  },
section: {
    flexDirection: "column",
    marginHorizontal: 14,
    marginBottom: 14,
    paddingBottom: 24,
    borderBottomColor: "#EAEAED",
    borderBottomWidth: 1
  },
 group: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    borderRadius: 14,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "#FF7657",
    display: "flex",
    flex: 1,
    width: "100%"
  },
})
```

Comment: Weird, tested your styles and worked well for me.

Comment: you mean the children filled the space?

Comment: Yes, it takes the same amount of space for each item

Comment: i wish it didn't :/ i settled with 0.33* width

Answer (score 0):

Somehow wrapping the TouchableOpacity with View and flex of 1 worked for me

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
   <TouchableOpacity
     style={[
      styles.button,
      styles.last,
      sort === "reviews" ? styles.active : null
     ]}
     onPress={() => setFilters({ sort: "reviews" })}
   >
     <Text
       style={[
        styles.buttonText,
        sort === "reviews" ? styles.activeText : null
       ]}
     >
       Reviews
     </Text>
   </TouchableOpacity>
 </View>
```